# Kafka Not Deleting Old Records

Tags: apache-kafka, aws-msk

I have an AWS Cluster kafka topic (MSK AWS) set to both compact and delete and would like to keep the messages no longer than 14 days so I've set

`retention.ms=1209600000`

However, I can see messages 1+ year older in my topic. This is my config on a topic and cluster level. Any ideas why it wouldn't delete older messages?

```
  segment.jitter.ms=0
  cleanup.policy=compact,delete
  flush.ms=9223372036854775807
  segment.bytes=1073741824
  retention.ms=1209600000
  flush.messages=9223372036854775807
  message.format.version=2.8-IV1
  max.compaction.lag.ms=86400000
  file.delete.delay.ms=60000
  max.message.bytes=1048588
  min.compaction.lag.ms=0
  message.timestamp.type=CreateTime
  index.interval.bytes=4096
  min.cleanable.dirty.ratio=0.5
  unclean.leader.election.enable=true
  retention.bytes=-1
  delete.retention.ms=86400000
  segment.ms=604800000
  message.timestamp.difference.max.ms=9223372036854775807
  segment.index.bytes=10485760
```

Comment: Are you seeing any records being deleted at all or are they all persistent?

Comment: Do you understand what `retention.bytes=-1` does?

Comment: yew I do, according to docs it means - 

This configuration controls the maximum size a partition (which consists of log segments) can grow to before we will discard old log segments to free up space if we are using the "delete" retention policy. By default there is no size limit only a time limit.

So even if there's no size limit, the time limit should kick in and discard old messages?